# Count the total number of names in a 'while loop' from user input, in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a code in Python using the *while loop* to do the following:

1. Require the user to **enter the names of all pupils in a class.**
2. The user should be able to type **“Stop”** to indicate that the names of all the students have been entered.
3. Print out the **total number of names the users entered after the loop has been exited.**

Here is the is the code I thus far:

```
print ("""Enter the names of all the pupils in your class.
Type 'Stop' to indicate that all the names have been entered.""")

count_names = {}

while True:
    pupil_names = input("Enter a name: ")
    # I know there is code missing here, but I can not figure out what it must be
    # I have 'count_names' as my counter variable

    if pupil_names == "Stop":
            print(f"There are {count_names} students")
        
            break
```

I have searched everywhere for help but can't find anything.
Answers / Help that have come the closest:
[count number of names in list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118273/count-number-of-names-in-list-in-python)
[Counting the input in a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350021/counting-the-input-in-a-while-loop)

Comment: `count_names` should be a number, not a dictionary. Then you just add 1 to it each time through the loop.

Comment: The two questions you linked to are about counting repetitions of the same name, not for counting the total number of names entered.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, and yes I know. But I just added them to show research and that there where no other answers to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
print ("""Enter the names of all the pupils in your class.
Type 'Stop' to indicate that all the names have been entered.""")

count_names = 0 # Initialize count_names to 0

while True:
    pupil_names = input("Enter a name: ")
    
    if pupil_names == "Stop":
            print(f"There are {count_names} students")
            break

    count_names += 1 # Add 1 each time we count a pupil
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting `count_names` to `{}` you make it a *[dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)* which does not suit your purpose. You would either want to save all names to a *[list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp)* (`[]`) or just keep the number of names as a number (start with `0`).

```py
names_list = [] # version 1
names_count = 0 # version 2

while True:
    new_name = input("Enter a name: ")

    if new_name == "Stop":        
        break

    names_list.append(new_name) # version 1
    names_count += 1            # version 2

print(f"There are {len(names_list)} students") # version 1
print(f"There are {names_count} students")     # version 2
```

Also, I put the `print` statement outside of the while-block, as your task asked for it. It will run exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

change count_names to:

```
count_names = 0
```

and add the following line:

```
while True:
  pupil_names = input("Enter a name: ")
  count_names += 1
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps as this is my take on this problem:

```
print('''Enter the names of all the pupils in 
the class. Enter "Stop" once all the names have 
been entered.
''')

pupil_count = 0

while pupil_count >= 0:
   pupil_names = input("Enter a name: ")

   pupil_count += 1

   if pupil_names == "Stop":

       print(f"\nThe total number of pupils in the class is: {pupil_count - 1}")

       break
```